# Use puppeeter on cloud function for a long job

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I'm developing some cloud functions on Google Cloud Platform.
I need to scrape a web page, then I decided to use the nodeJS cloud functions with Puppeteer.

My scraper do a job that take 1 to 3 minutes to complete.

My idea was to trigger the function through an API call, return a success message and then scrape the page and save the data on a Database.

The following is my code.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');


async function browserPromise() {
    return await puppeteer.launch({
        args: [
            "--ignore-certificate-errors",
            "--no-sandbox",
        ],
        headless: true
    })
}

exports.Runner = async (req, res) => {

    const browser = await browserPromise();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({width: 1200, height: 720});

    scraper(browser, page, req.body)

    res.json('OK')
}


async function scraper(browser, page, formdata) { 
...do stuff...
}
```

The problem is that when I run the code above, I receive the response "OK" but the code inside the scraper always fails with the following error

```
Error: Process exited with code 16
    at process.<anonymous>
```

Instead, if I wait for a response like the following it works.

```
const data = await scraper(browser, page, req.body)
```

The problem is that if I use the above method the client that call my function has to wait 1 minute and then see a timeout message.
I would like to let the client see a succesfull message and then do all the scrape in the background.

What's the best way to do what I need to do?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it will take time to init the browser, create page, and do the other things you want to do.

You need to check which step(s) taken the time too long.

```
console.time('method1');
console.timeEnd('method1');
```

And I'm using these args:

```
var args = [
            '--proxy-server='+proxy,
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
            '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
            '--no-first-run',
            '--no-zygote',
            '--single-process'
        ];
```

and you have to use

```
scraper(browser, page, req.body)
```

instead of

```
await scraper(browser, page, req.body)
```

before the response send